# Wordpress website theme, hosting choice

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins, themes

I am new to word press. I would like to create a website that would have registered users with log in, able to accept online payments, able to upload documents by users and by administrator into a secure location unique for each user and protected by log in . I also would like to add 2nd language option where the website would change from one language to another language at a click of a button.
I need help with the choice of hosting service and theme and plugins to accomplish this task.
Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. of all For hosting You can contact me, I have a linux server running many quality websites so you can try it out but if you are really interested to spending a lot amount of money on hosting I will sugest you to go for WPEngines or purchase dedicated server.
2. For the language thing, your theme must have a new language (e.g spanish) .mo and .po file or you can use Google Translator plugin in sidebar.
3. The requirements you have said, generally you need to made a custom theme for it.

You will find many other wordpress tutorials here: http://9tutorials.org/tutorials/wordpress/